# How do I model a many-to-many relationship over 3 tables in SQLAlchemy (ORM)?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm rusty in SQL and completely new to [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), but have an upcoming project which uses both. So I thought I write something to get comfortable. Suffering from a hangover I decided to write something to keep track of alcohol levels.

I have **`events`** where **`users`** participate and consume **`drinks`**. Those are my three basic tables (with one helper table `guestlist`, for a m:n relationship between *users* and *events*).

*drinks* list the drinks available at all *events* to all *users* all the time (no need to map anything). *users* are created from time to time, so are *events*. all users can join all *events*, so I use the `guestlist` table to map those.

**Now to the heart of the question:** I need to keep track at what time which user consumes which drink on which event. I try to solve this whit another table `shots` (see below) but I'm not sure if this a good solution.

[image: ERP Diagram]
<sub>(source: [anyimg.com](http://s1.anyimg.com/img/g6ld1ku/Bildschirmfoto.png))</sub>

In [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) it might look somewhat like this (or not, but this is what I came up with so far)::

```
guestlist_table = Table('guestlist', Base.metadata,
    Column('event_id', Integer, ForeignKey('events.id')),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class Event(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'events'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
  started = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, index=True,
    default=datetime.datetime.now
  )
  users = relationship("User", secondary=guestlist_table, backref="events")
  # ...

class User(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'users'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
  birthdate = Column(Date, nullable=False)
  weight = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
  sex = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
  # ...

class Drink(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'drinks'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
  volume = Column(Numeric(5,2), nullable=False)
  percent = Column(Numeric(5,2), nullable=False)
  # ...

class Shots(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'shots'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False,
    default=datetime.datetime.now
  )
  user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)
  event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('events.id'), index=True) 
  drink_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('drinks.id'))
  user = relationship("User", backref="shots")
  event = relationship("Event", backref="shots")
  drink = relationship("Drink", uselist=False) # one-to-one, no backref needed
```

I struggle to find a good way to build a table that maps *events*, *users* and *drinks* together: **How should I formulate the [relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationships.html) and how do I [query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) it?**

The thing is I kinda feel I overlooked something. 
And frankly I'm absolute lost on how to **query** it?

Here are the queries I would make most of the time:

- I at least need to get all the shots consumed on a event (probably sorted by user)
- I also sometimes need all shots for a specific user (probably sorted by event)
- And a lot of counting:

  - Number of shots per event
  - Number of shots per user
  - Number of shots a user downed at a event

Is the `shots` table a okay way to manage this?

Comment: Hello @Brutus, As per my view your relationship is like 1 user can participate in many event and 1 event has many user (guestlist). 1 event has many drinks and 1 drink can serve in many event (drinklist). 1 user can take many drinks and 1 drinks can serve to many user (guestdrinklist). Is this correct?

Comment: All drinks are available at all events, so I thought I might not need `drinklist`. What you called `guestdrinklist` I tried to model in the `Shots` class. Would it be better to split the class in two tables?

Comment: If all drinks are available at all events then no need to specify relationship between drinks and events. You have to specify relationship if subset of your field is associated with other entity if all is associated then there is no relationship needed. You can create relationship between drinks and user.

Comment: I think the answer from Victor covers it all very nicely. In fact, quering for all kinds of reporting should be pretty easy. And if you need those for reporting, i would definitely try to do those in a query so that that you get as few SQL statements as possible for each part of report. However, you might want to have some of those as properties (see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html?highlight=object_session#building-query-enabled-properties). You model is very good. One definite thing to add though is a composite `FK` from `Shots` to `guestlist` table (next comment).

Comment: `__table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["user_id", "event_id"],
            ["guestlist.user_id", "guestlist.event_id"],
            name="fk_guestlist",
        ),
    )`

Comment: Thanks van. I will test everything once I'm back home. (I accepted Victor's answer, although I havn't tested it, but it seems solid.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to draw an Entity Relationship Diagram, it would be much more clear for people and you to understand your question.

To answer your question:

> I at least need to get all the shots consumed on a event (probably sorted by user)

To get all shots of an event, you could try

```
session.query(Shots).filter_by(event_id=event_id)
```

The event_id is the id of event you like to query. To store by user, you can try

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import desc, asc
session.query(Shots) \
    .filter_by(event_id=event_id) \
    .order_by(asc(Shots.user_id))
```

Of course, you may want to sort by attribute of an user, you could join user table.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import desc, asc
session.query(Shots) \
    .filter_by(event_id=event_id) \
    .join(User) \
    .order_by(asc(User.name))
```

easy enough.

> I also sometimes need all shots for a specific user (probably sorted by event)

Just like previous example

> Number of shots per event

```
session.query(Shots) \
    .filter_by(event_id=event_id) \
    .count()
```

I didn't run they, I just wrote them here, but they should all work if I didn't make a typo.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I try it out as soon as I get home. I also added an ERP. And about my table layout: Do you think the `shots` table is a valid way to map the data together, given my queries-cases? Or should I use another approach to organizing the tables and relationships?